# whatever the number , i enter in form field, i want that to be stored in a variable.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(web designing) whatever the number , i enter in form field, i want that to be stored  in a variable. When the user changes the value in the form field , value stored in the variable needs to be updated. How to do that ?

Comment: take a look at the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: try jquery da pranav @Kannan K answer is good :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type = "text" id = "id1">

<script>
     $("#id1").change(function(){
     var a = $("#id1").val();
     alert(a);
     }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a jsbin that demonstrates required functionality

[jsbin](http://%3Ca%20href=%22http://jsbin.com/luyutapehu/edit?html,console,output%22%3E%20jsbin%3C/%3E)

or

```
<form>
    <input id="input" type="number">
</form>
<button id="button">Log Value</button>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var val;

    input.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        val = +event.target.value;
    });
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('Value:', val);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form>
<input type="text" id="inputid" value="test"/>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var input =$('#inputid');
  var saveVar;
//   input.change(function(){
// console.log(input.val());
//   });
input.on('keyup', function(ev){
  saveVar=input.val();
 console.log(saveVar);

});
});
    </script>
```